# How to diagnose dll load problem for Perl Module Lab::VISA

Tags: perl, dll

I have successfully installed (i.e without errors or warnings) as per the instructions:

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Lab-VISA/lib/Lab/VISA/Installation.pod

But when I try to run the example script I get:

```
Can't load 'C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/auto/Lab/VISA/VISA.dll' for module
Lab::VISA: load_file:The specified module could not be found at 
 C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 190.
 at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Lab/VISA.pm line 11
Compilation failed in require at VISA Test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at VISA Test.pl line 3.
```

Googling this suggests the there is something wrong with VISA.dll. This is generated during the install of the module, so I guess it is something in my environment. But my limited knowledge means I am not sure where to start. And I cannot seem to find a help contact or forum for Lab::VISA module.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in metacpan :

```
On 64-bit windows one needs a 32-bit version of perl with GNU binutils version <= 2.24. Otherwise linking with the NI-VISA library will fail. The reason for this are the following bugs in the GNU binutils:

binutils bug 16598

binutils bug 17910

These are fixed in the most recent version of the binutils. Once this version (2.26) is included in Strawberry Perl, it should be possible to use a 64-bit version of perl.

It is not possible to use either 32-bit or 64-bit versions of Strawberry Perl 5.22 as this version uses binutils 2.25.
```

So if you have WIN 64 , you need to install `binutils`

binutils bug 16598 : https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16598

and binutils bug 17910 : https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17910

Notice : don't forget to always read documentations

Comment: I saw that too just before posting, and checked my versions. I am using an old version of strawberry Perl for other reasons (5.14.2.1) which has older binutils, so it compiles. If I use the latest strawberry Perl then it fails to link.